# Filter selected children from data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, filter

I try to write a function in JavaScript which filter an array by a selected property (an value).

But it works for 2 level only I do not understand what do I missing.

The data I want to filter:

```
  var data = [

    {
        name: "john_pc",
        children: [
            {
                name: "sabrina_pc",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "sabrina_pc"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "john_pc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "john_pc"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        name: "sabrina_pc"
    }
]
```

The childrenFilter funciton :

```
const childrenFilter = (childrenData, filters) => {
    let filteredData = childrenData.filter(item => {
        for (var property in filters) {
            var optionalValues = filters[property];
            var value = item[property];
            if (item.children) {
                item.children = childrenFilter(item.children, filters);
            }
            let hasValue = value == optionalValues;
            if (hasValue) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }, this);
    return filteredData;
}
```

Calling the function:

As you can see the 'childrenFilter' get an object which the key is property in the data and the key is value I want to keep.

    `let result = childrenFilter(data, {
        "name": "a1"
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))`

The wanted result :

```
  [
    {
        "name": "john_pc",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "sabrina_pc",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "john_pc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "john_pc"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. please choose unique names.

Comment: For an object to be included, does it have to match all the filters or just one of them?

Comment: It is a good question.Maybe I should add third argument to do both

Comment: can you show a more realistic example instead of a bunch of a1 and a2?

Comment: If you could post what your wanting as a result that would really help us to assist you. Also when posting a recursive function comments and specific naming _really_ helps. It may be clear to you, but to anyone who didn't write it, this particular recursive function may be difficult to wrap their head around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter function does not take into account whether or not children elements match the pattern, therefore even though some child elements of the object match the pattern, the object itself is being filtered out.

Here is the explanation:

```
        {
            name: "a2", // does not match filter {name:'a1} so is removed alongside child objects
            children: [ // gets removed with parent object
                {
                    name: "a2"
                },
                {
                    name: "a1" 
                }
            ]
        }
```

This should produce the desired output:

```
    const childrenFilter = (childrenData, filters) => {
    let filteredData = childrenData.filter(item => {
        for (var property in filters) {
            var optionalValues = filters[property];
            var value = item[property];
            if (item.children) {
                item.children = childrenFilter(item.children, filters);
            }
            let hasValue = value == optionalValues;
            if (hasValue || item.children.length) { // include item when children mathes the pattern
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }, this);
    return filteredData;
    }
```

Comment: Right... How do you recommend to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You could build new array for each step of filtering, beginning from the leaves and check if this contains the wanted value.

This approach generates new objects and does not mutate the original data.

```js
function filter(array, filters) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var children = filter(o.children || [], filters);
        return children || Object.entries(filters).every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v)
            ? (r || []).concat(Object.assign({}, o, children && { children }))
            : r;
    }, undefined);
}

var data = [{ name: "a1", children: [{ name: "a2", children: [{ name: "a2" }, { name: "a1" }] }, { name: "a1" }] }, { name: "b1" }];
    
console.log(filter(data, { name: "a1" }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```